Interpretation of time series spectral entropy values wrt forecastability by a general neural network
I recently started using spectral entropy to analyze time series (already windowed). I'm having difficulty for interpreting the results, the entropy of the last 25% of a series is 0.19, and the entropy of the entire series is 0.23, does this make sense? Isn't the more data a neural network has, it's better to forecast, for example? Mainly considering the fact that the last 25% of the data does not encompass a complete distribution, for example, the test data has a different distribution than the training data.
